# Definition fo object representation and operator sizeof

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

The definition of object representation concept is given in 3.9/4:

[basic.types]

> The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N
>   unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals
>   `sizeof(T)`.

But `sizeof` operator's defined as follows:

[expr.sizeof]

> The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the *object*
>   *representation* of its operand.

In particular:

> When applied to a class, the result is the number of bytes in an
>   object of that class including any padding required for placing
>   objects of that type in an array

I'd like to consider that definition by example:

```
struct A {
    int a;  //sizeof(a) is implementation defined
    long b; //sizeof(b) is implementation defined
    char c; //sizeof(c) is 1 by definition 
    // Padding, problbly equals to 3 butes
}
```

How is `sizeof(A)` computed by implementation? We just compute the sum of `sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) + sizeof(c) + padding`.

But what is the condition `required for placingobjects of that type in an array` about?

Comment: Arrays must be contiguous. Objects need to be properly aligned.

Comment: @T.C. Is object representation of all types expect _narrow character types_ implementation defined due to sizeof thereof is?

Comment: @T.C. About the struct I defined in the question. That means a padding  added by implementation is also undefined, right? That's the padding added to ability to store an object of the struct into an array may be large enough. I tried to sure, but both clang and gcc gives the same sizeof.

Answer (score 0):

You simple compute the size of struct as:

```
long size = sizeof(struct A);
```

And if you want an array of `struct A`,

```
struct A arr[/* Size of array */];
```